# Why Are My Cell's Images Being Pixelated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I am using an iPhone 4 with retina display.

I have a 60x60 png that was downsized from a 500x500 png that I am using as the cell's imageView.

For some reason, the image looks a bit pixelated and blurry, basically not up to retina display standards.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a a 60x60 png as a source. It will likely resolve your bluriness problems and will additionaly be cheaper on memory usage.

I have also experienced resized images to be blurry and the likes. I could imagine that this has something todo with the images being shrunken down at runtime, though I'm not sure about that.

Also remember that it's recommended to provide two versions of your imagefile:

- One for normal resolutions (iPhone 3G, 3GS ...): picture.png for your case: 30x30px
- One for the retina display (iPhone 4): picture@2x.png for your case: 60x60px.

Comment: The picture file is already a 60x60.  It is not being downsized at runtime.

Comment: Ok, then you should be fine with just following the @2x naming convention :)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html The section "Points vs. Pixels" is a recommended read regarding that topic :)

Comment: Thanks Julian, I just did that and named it "picture@2x.png", but now the image is very small in the cell.  Maybe 60x60 is too small for retina?  What size should it be if my row.height = 70?

Comment: 70 is the height in points, so I guess something in the region of 110-120px should be appropriate. Again, I relly recommend you read the article I posted :)

Comment: Thanks, I found 120x120 is perfect.  I don't have a non-retina device to test on, but 50% of the size should be fine for non-retina iPhone correct? So 60x60.

Comment: In response... if you're adding a retina version with an "@2x" in the file name, it needs to be twice the pixel size of what you need to show the user. In other words, an image you want to show as a 60x60 image should have an actual size of 120x120.

Answer (score 0):

Since the filename doesn't follow the `base@2x.ext` format, iOS doesn't recognize it should use a scale factor of 2. There are two solutions:

The best is to provide two versions of the image: one for non-retina displays, which would be named `picture.png` and another one twice as big for retina displays, which would be named `picture@2x.png`. You would still use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];`, iOS automagically notices when the device has a retina display and there is a file called `picture@2x.png` that it needs to use that instead.

The hacky solution (which would make your image appear twice as big on non-retina devices) is to do this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
cell.imageView.image.scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

I recommend to go the `@2x` way, this is how it's supposed to be done.

Comment: The scale is a read only parameter (At least in iOS 5.1).
The hack is 
            UIImage* image = //somehow get normal res image
            if ([UIScreen mainScreen]scale] == 2)
            { 
                image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image
                                                   CGImage] scale:2 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            }